# Lower the position of a parallax element

Tags: jquery, html, web, parallax

I'm building a website for my friends wedding (http://mhutchinson.me.uk/tom/) and I'm using parallax to make the white 'save the date' text disappear under the cream section with the details in it.

I have the basic functionality working but I cannot get 'save the date' image to sit lower down. It always butts up against the top or if I move it down it doesn't work properly.

Does anyone have any idea of how to position it?

Here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
    //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
    //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
    //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport

    $('#intro').parallax("50%", 0.4);
    $('#logo').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('#infoWrapper').parallax("50%", 0.1);
})
```

Comment: Which parallax plugin are you using? All you need to do is set vertical position of the background. It seems to be overwritten when scrolling starts.

Comment: im Using this one http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 0):

On your CSS try to remove the "background-attachment: fixed" rule and use  this.

```
  background-image: url(yourimage.path);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center bottom!important;
  top: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 200;
```